# SQL datetime out of range error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am calling a stored procedure from another stored procedure. I need to pass parameter `@StartDate` and `@enddate`:

```
Create procedure GetALL
    (@Startdate datetime,
     @EndDate datetime)
as
    insert into #test 
       Exec [getCustomerAll] @Startdate, @EndDate
```

I am getting an error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

I cannot modify the `getCustomerAll` stored procedure as it is written by a third party client

The parameters for `GetCustomerAll`, `@Startdate` and `@EndDate` are all of type `datetime`.

I am calling `GetALL` stored procedure from C# asp.net.

```
exec  GetALL  '15 MAY 2016','15 MAY 2016' .
```

The issue occuring on calling GetCustomer all

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCustomerAll]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @DateFrom Datetime,
    @DateTo Datetime,

AS
BEGIN


    SELECT  * from Customers

    WHERE creation_date BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DateFrom, 103) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DateTo, 103)
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Can you show your C#?

Comment: could you please share "getCustomerAll" code?

Comment: So you are basically saying that there's a varchar conversion problem but you don't show the failing code? What could we do? Are you calling your SP by sending a string like that? Or a parametrized call? Can't you share anything else about the exception you are getting? Does the issue occur when calling `GetALL` or when calling `GetCustomerAll`?

Comment: @Andrew i have updated

Comment: What column type is `creation_date`? `varchar`? Can create a similar SP named `getCustomerAll_Test` for example and make it only have `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DateFrom, 103), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DateTo, 103)`? If then you call it from `GetALL` you can test if the issue lies in the converting or somewhere else (you may have to temporarily comment the `insert into #test` line). Give you have access to the code, you should be able to debug it to find where the problem occurs...

Answer (score 0):

Call procedure using generic date format:

```
exec  GetALL '20160515','20160515'
```

Comment: Please try     exec  GetALL  '2016-05-15','2016-05-15'

Comment: No need to apply cast. The datetime format is already in YYYYMMDD format. Casting is additional overhead here.

Answer (score 0):

try calling GetALL stored procedure in the following way

```
declare @Startdate as datetime,@EndDate as datetime;
set @Startdate=convert(datetime, '15 MAY 2016',106);
set @EndDate=convert(datetime, '15 MAY 2016',106);
exec  GetALL  @Startdate,@EndDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creation_Date is a date-time column ?

Why are you converting @DateFrom & @DateTo to varchar(10) using convert() ?

```
WHERE creation_date BETWEEN 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DateFrom, 103) 
      AND 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DateTo, 103)
```

Comment: that stored procedure is not written by me. It is an existing stored procedure in the system. I cannot modify it

Comment: but you can execute SQL Select statement with filters ... Check if it gives any error ?